# How to generate a default value of new not null column in existing database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a existing database.Need to add new not null column with default value.The same can be done in hibernate 4.3 using ValueGenerator interface.But my project has hibernate 3.6 which does not provide this functionality.Is there any way to do this using hibernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can acchive with  @Column with nullable attribute
e.g:

```
 @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name = "Jhon Doe";
```

Also a little bit of a hack using the columnDefinition property of the @Column annotation, for example:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="double precision default '96'")
private Double grolsh;
```

Comment: This will work for new table.I have existimg table with entries in it.Need to add default values in existing table entres.

Comment: what is hibernate ddl auto configuration setting on your project, is it update?

Comment: then it should work., use columnDefinition attribute for default value

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by sql itself.

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
[WITH VALUES]
```

E.g:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

Answer (score 0):

An example from the hibernate docu (for the default):

```
@Column(name = "INITIAL_PRICE",
columnDefinition = "number(10,2) default '1'")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(
org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime.INSERT
)
private BigDecimal initalPrice;
```

And for the nullable you can use

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

Comment: Hi @tomas i am using annotation based mapping.So there is no hbm file.

Comment: I changed the answer to annotations

Comment: Tried but id did not create any column in db.